# Access JLabel from other class , Swingworker

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel, swingworker

I have 2 classes. One class is for gui and the other class doing some staff. 
The second class includes Swingworker. It searches some log files and take some sentence from there. Also in the gui there is a label which writes in `Searching.. Please wait..` and when the second class finish the work, it should be changed to `Searching is finished..` .

This label name is `searchLabel`and define in first class. It is private variable.

My purpose is : In the second class there is `done` method. Inside in this method, I want to do `searchLabel.setText("blabla");`

How can I do this ? I cannot access. Also doing public JLabel is not a solution I think.
You can easily find that part in the code with searcing `/* PROBLEM IS IN HERE */` this string.

**Here is the code**

This is my gui class :

```
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Dimension;
 import java.awt.EventQueue;
 import java.awt.Font;
 import java.awt.Toolkit;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JComboBox;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.JTextField;
 import javax.swing.UIManager;
 import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
 import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
 import javax.swing.JTable;
 import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

 public class mainGui extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField userNametextField;
public static JLabel searchLabel,userNameWarningLabel,pathWarningLabel;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and feel.
    }
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                mainGui frame = new mainGui();
                Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
                int w = frame.getSize().width;
                int h = frame.getSize().height;
                int x = (dim.width-w)/4;
                int y = (dim.height-h)/2;  
                frame.setLocation(x, y);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
 }

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public mainGui() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 550, 455);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    setTitle("Role Finding Script");
    //  Border border;

    JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("   Username  :");
    lblUsername.setFont(new Font("LucidaSans", Font.BOLD, 13));
    lblUsername.setBounds(10, 53, 113, 30);
    //Border border = BorderFactory.createRaisedSoftBevelBorder();
    //  border = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder();
    //  lblUsername.setBorder(border);
    getContentPane().add(lblUsername);


    userNametextField = new JTextField();
    userNametextField.setBounds(146, 53, 250, 30);
    userNametextField.setFont(new Font("LucidaSans", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    getContentPane().add(userNametextField);
    userNametextField.setColumns(20);

    JLabel lblRole = new JLabel("    Roles        :");
    lblRole.setFont(new Font("LucidaSans", Font.BOLD, 13));
    lblRole.setBounds(10, 124, 113, 30);
    //  border = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder();
    //  lblRole.setBorder(border);
    getContentPane().add(lblRole);

    JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
    comboBox.setBounds(146, 124, 250, 30);
    comboBox.addItem("VR_ANALYST1");
    comboBox.addItem("VR_ANALYST2");
    comboBox.addItem("VR_ANALYST3");
    comboBox.addItem("VR_ANALYST4");
    comboBox.addItem("VR_ANALYST5");
    comboBox.addItem("VR_ANALYST6");
    comboBox.addItem("VR_ANALYST7");
    comboBox.addItem("VR_ANALYST8");
    comboBox.addItem("VR_ANALYST9");
    comboBox.addItem("VR_ANALYST10");
    comboBox.addItem("VR_ANALYST11");
    comboBox.addItem("VR_ANALYST12");
    comboBox.setMaximumRowCount(6);
    getContentPane().add(comboBox);


    this.searchLabel = new JLabel("Searching.. Please wait..");
    searchLabel.setFont(new Font("LucidaSans", Font.BOLD, 13));
    searchLabel.setBounds(169, 325, 195, 30);
    searchLabel.setVisible(false);
    getContentPane().add(searchLabel);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Show Me ");
    btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("LucidaSans", Font.BOLD, 13));
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(userNametextField.getText() == null || userNametextField.getText().equals("")){
                userNameWarningLabel.setText("Please filled in the Username part.");

            }else{
                searchLabel.setVisible(true);
                VolvoMain task = new VolvoMain();
                task.execute();
            }


        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(188, 271, 126, 30);
    getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

    JLabel lblPath = new JLabel("    Path         :");
    lblPath.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 13));
    lblPath.setBounds(10, 195, 113, 30);
    getContentPane().add(lblPath);

    userNameWarningLabel = new JLabel("");
    userNameWarningLabel.setBounds(156, 89, 227, 14);
    userNameWarningLabel.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.ITALIC, 10));  
    userNameWarningLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
    getContentPane().add(userNameWarningLabel);

    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("...");
    btnNewButton_1.setBounds(412, 195, 30, 30);
    getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);

    JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("+");
    btnNewButton_2.setBounds(460, 195, 44, 30);
    getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_2);

    JLabel headerLabel = new JLabel("Find the Role");
    headerLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
    headerLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    headerLabel.setBounds(94, 11, 358, 30);
    headerLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
    getContentPane().add(headerLabel);

    pathWarningLabel = new JLabel("");
    pathWarningLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
    pathWarningLabel.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.ITALIC, 10));
    pathWarningLabel.setBounds(156, 236, 227, 14);
    getContentPane().add(pathWarningLabel);
}
 }
```

And this is the other class :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;


public class VolvoMain extends SwingWorker{

    private  FileInputStream fstream;
    private  BufferedReader br;
    private  String username = "HALAA";
    private  String role = "VR_ANALYST";
    private  String firstLine = "";
    private  Pattern regex;
    private  List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private  File dir;
    private mainGui mg = new mainGui();

    //String reg = "\\t'AUR +(" + username + ") .*? /ROLE=\"(" + role + ")\".*$";


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {

        String fmt = "\\t'AUR +(%s) .*? /ROLE=\"(%s)\".*$";
        String reg = String.format(fmt, username, role);

        regex = Pattern.compile(reg);


        dir = new File(
                "C:"+File.separator+"Documents and Settings"+File.separator+"sbx1807"+File.separator+"Desktop"+File.separator
                +"Batu"+File.separator+"Deneme"+File.separator
                );

        File[] dirs = dir.listFiles();

        String[] txtArray = new String[dirs.length];

        int z=0;
        for (File file : dirs) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {

            }else {
                if(file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".log")){
                    txtArray[z] = file.getAbsolutePath();
                    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    z++;
                }
            }

            int j = 0;

            for(int i=0; i<txtArray.length; i++){
                if(txtArray[i] != null && !txtArray[i].equals("")){
                    try{
                        fstream = new FileInputStream(txtArray[i]);
                        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
                        String strLine;

                        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                            /* parse strLine to obtain what you want */
                            if((j%2)== 0){
                                firstLine = strLine;
                            }
                            if(((j%2) != 0) && regex.matcher(strLine).matches()){
                                stringList.add(firstLine);
                                stringList.add(strLine);
                            }
                            publish(stringList.size());
                            j++;
                        }
                        publish(stringList.size());
                        br.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
            for(int k=0; k<stringList.size(); k++){
                System.out.println(stringList.get(k));
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void done() {
        System.out.println("bitti");
    //  getSearchJLabel().setText("Searching is done..");
    //  mainGui m = new mainGui();
    //  m.searchLabel.setText("done");

    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Don't set the size of top level containers.  Instead layout the content & call `pack()`. 3) Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Comment: I cut the code in some parts

Comment: Note.  I did not advise to edit to a short code snippet, but an SSCCE.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your `VolvoMain` class so it takes a reference to the `JLabel` in its constructor. Store this in a `private final` field and you can use this in the `done()` method.

```
public class VolvoMain extends SwingWorker{

    // ...

    private final JLabel labelToUpdate;

    public VolvoMain(JLabel labelToUpdate) {
      this.labelToUpdate = labelToUpdate;
    }

    // ...

    @Override
    public void done() {        
      // Update labelToUpdate here
    }
```

The `done()` method will be invoked on the Event Dispatch Thread, so it will be safe to adjust the label text directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I dont understand, what do you want to mean with `Adjust your Volvomain class`